# windows porting: MSVC, STL Containers, RVO and dllexport

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, stl, visual-studio-2015

i'm currently trying to port a library initially coded for Linux, in windows but i'm encountering quite an issue here.

Since i mostly used C++11 feats the porting went well at first, but it started to get messy when i tried to export symbols along with my DLL.

Indeed, a lot of exported classes members return STL containers. it didn't matter at the time since the RVO feat in modern compilers do the trick, but now MSVC is warning that my exported class members shouldn't return STL containers. This is an issue because i have some almost everywhere in my code, so i can't change/wrap them just for porting purposes. So finally my question is: is this warning really important, and have my dll good chances to work even if the client program using it was not compiled with the same STL version ?

thank you very much,

Regards,
Clément.

Comment: Short answer : there is no ABI compatibility between code compiled with different versions of the runtime (read : different visual studio versions), so if you are returning STL types, you'd better make sure that the library and the program that use it use the same runtime (also beware of debug versions of the runtime). I'll let experts in Windows programming answer something more precise, but the bottom line is that you can't mix runtime versions, period.

Comment: Thanks for the answer..then i guess i'll make my lib static rather than dynamic, or maybe better: failback to a good'ol cygwin port..i guess it will leave me in peace for good, i don't want to waste my time on such futilities